# Skip the servlet filter for ajax request

Tags: html, ajax, servlets, servlet-filters

How can I skip the execution in `doFilter` for only an Ajax request?

As of now I am passing parameter called `isAjax`. Is there a "standard" way to do this?

How can I stop execution in filter in this scenario? Will adding `return` statement be a proper approach?

Comment: Can this help : http://hanuska.blogspot.in/2009/07/detect-ajax-request.html ?

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705028/redirecting-a-web-client-from-a-servlet-filter-client-server-connection-via-aja

Answer (score 4):

Most browsers add a special request-header when sending AJAX requests. You can easily check that using this snippet:

```
public static boolean isAjaxRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return "XMLHttpRequest".equals(request.getHeader("X-Requested-With"));
}
```

Note, however, that this is no perfect guarantee, as this header starts with `X-`, it is not a standard header and browsers / client code may decide not to send it.

Answer (score 0):

Your filter is declared in web.xml file and it is declared some-like to such:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>NonAjaxServiceFiler</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/non-ajax/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

So every query not matched to 'non-ajax' will be bypassed

Comment: Perhaps, then he will have to re-write all Ajax URLs ;)